# My location restriction to admin panel is not working in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My website is at `https://www.example.com`  and I have a CMS Panel at

`https://www.example.com/administrator` -> 301 ->
`https://www.example.com/administrator/` -> 302
`https://www.example.com/administrator/Login.aspx?Session=Out`

And I am trying to restrict the access to /administrator but this is not working - Can someone please help?

```
location ~*/administrator {
allow 10.0.0.0/8;
deny all;
}
```

here are the logs

```
192.168.5.232 - - [20/Apr/2023:09:17:57 +0530] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/2.0" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
192.168.5.232 - - [20/Apr/2023:09:17:57 +0530] "GET /administrator/Login.aspx?Session=Out HTTP/2.0" 200 2448 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
```

Here are error logs

```
2023/04/20 09:15:34 [notice] 4810#4810: *467 "GET|HEAD|POST" matches "GET", client: 192.168.5.232, server: example.com, request: "GET /administrator/error HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/administrator/Login.aspx?Session=Out"
2023/04/20 09:17:57 [notice] 4962#4962: *513 "GET|HEAD|POST" matches "GET", client: 192.168.5.232, server: example.com, request: "GET /administrator/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com"
2023/04/20 09:17:57 [notice] 4962#4962: *513 "GET|HEAD|POST" matches "GET", client: 192.168.5.232, server: example.com, request: "GET /administrator/Login.aspx?Session=Out HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com"
```

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters or see Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Comment: This is not related to web hosting control panel but challenge in configuration on reverse proxy in nginx. Its an nginx issue hence I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions here. Just the directory should do it

```
location /administrator/ {
allow 10.0.0.0/8;
deny all;
}
```

And you were missing a blank after `~*`, which was most probably the actual problem.

Comment: Let me see if that works? Since I guess I already tried that but it did not work.

Comment: Nah its still not working
location ^~  /(administrator|Administrator|Login\.aspx) {
       allow 49.36.10.215;
       deny all;
        return 403;
}